# MongoDB: exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file error because of changing dbpath

Tags: mongodb, config, ubuntu-16.04, mount

I'm trying to run mongod on a server (VM on a server) with the modified dbpath. I've tested it with the default dbpath and it was OK.

This is the command and the error I got:

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3350 port=27017 dbpath=/mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/ 64-bit host=PROJET-CIRMAR2
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.1
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 5e103c4f5583e2566a45d740225dc250baacfbd7
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise 
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-02-01T10:31:44.272+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/" } }
2017-02-01T10:31:50.291+0100 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/mongod.lock No locks available. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-02-01T10:31:50.291+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-02-01T10:31:50.292+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-02-01T10:31:50.292+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-02-01T10:31:50.292+0100 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

After checking the directory, I saw that the mongod.lock file was created but the server wasn't able to run properly.

I tried these two commands separately but the result was the same.

```
sudo chown mongodb /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/
```

and

```
sudo chown pilmngr /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/
```

I've also changed the `dbPath` in the `mongod.conf` file. And to know more about the directory:

```
df -h
Filesystem                                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                         981M     0  981M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                        201M  3.2M  197M   2% /run
/dev/vda1                                     18G  3.9G   13G  24% /
tmpfs                                       1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                       1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
192.168.73.1:/volume2/projets/PROJET-CIRMAR   11T  535G  9.8T   6% /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR
tmpfs
```

So, I think the directory is something like an external hard disk mounted. I tried to run the MongoDB using another directory (not on `/mnt/...`) and it worked, too. Do you have any solution??

Comment: The error hints " Is a mongod instance already running?". Do you check that?

Comment: @gzc This is the problem! It's not possible to run the mongod! I tried `sudo mongod --dbpath /mnt/PROJET-CIRMAR/aisdb/` to run it but I got the error I mentioned.

Comment: Please show output of `ps aux | grep mongod`. I mean there may already be a running mongod instance.

Comment: And, another problem is that when I try to run mongod using `mongod` for example, it ignores the modified dbPath in the config file! It tries to run it with the default dbPath! So, I should mention the modified dbPath `using --dbpath` option.

Comment: @gzc This is its output: `pilmngr   3429  0.0  0.0  14244  1088 pts/0    S+   11:44   0:00 grep --color=auto mongod`